# Why doesn't Spring tool suite's, tomcat server restart's mac keyboard shortcut work unless you click on server under "Servers" tab?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, keyboard-shortcuts, spring-tool-suite

I'm using tomcat server in Spring tool suite. 
I am trying to learn and remember keyboard shortcuts to be efficient. 
Whenever I do "Option" + "Command" + "R" it doesn't restart the server. 
But if I click the Tomcat server under "Servers" tab, and then if I use keyboard shortcut, it works. But that doesn't make efficient. Its double the work. 
Why is it so?
Is this a defect or missing something in settings?

Comment: By default, "Option" + "Command" + "R"  is set to run under "servers view".

Answer (score 1):

By default, "Option" + "Command" + "R" is set to run under "servers view". You can use "Option + Shift + X, R" instead to run on the server.

EDIT:
[image]
Key bindings can be changed as per your preference under 
Preferences --> General --> Keys

Comment: Is it Option + Shift + X, R or 
Option + Command + X,R ? I tried both and it didn't work. I want the keyboard shortcut to work where-ever I'm right now in Spring Tool suite (like Package explorer or editing code etc.)